# Parsing through two files while comparing values

Tags: c++, parsing, io, iostream, ifstream

Currently, I am given a task to add all the countries with respect to regions those countries contain into a mysql table...

At the moment, I am just going to write a program in C++ that parses two files, one that has country codes and the countries name, then the other file has country codes and regions with respect to their country codes.

So within the mysql tables i need to add the countries name and the region within such country...

So heres a line from the country code - country name file:

```
AD  Andorra
```

Heres a line from the country code - region name file:

```
ad,aixas,Aix‡s,06,,42.4833333,1.4666667
```

The country code-region name file is HUGE!!! So I first iterate through that file first... With every line in the country-code-region name file I access the other file and compare the first two characters of the country code - region name file to the country code - country name file. I am doing this because in the company web page, the drop down tables are supposed to show a country NAME not its abbreviation.

So heres my attempt on how I do it...

```
std::vector<std::string> countryRegionArray;
std::vector<std::string> countryCode;
std::string aline;
std::string bline;
std::ifstream myfile ("/Users/settingj/Documents/Country-State Parse/worldcitiespop.txt"); // country code to region
std::ifstream countryCodes ("/Users/settingj/Documents/Country-State Parse/countries.txt"); //country code to country

while (getline (myfile,aline))
{
    std::string countryCode; // the country code string
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // loop through the first two characters of the text file to retrieve the Country code
        countryCode.push_back(toupper(aline[i])); // push the characters into a vector and convert them to uppercase to compare later

    while (getline(countryCodes, bline)) // if the file is readable
    {
        std::string country; // declare a string variable to store the comparing country code
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // loop through the first two characters of the country code text file
            country.push_back(bline[i]); // push the first two characters into the string variable declared in the previous scope

        if (countryCode == country) // if string and country code are equal, change countrycode to the last characters of the string in the country-code ->country text file
        {
            std::string countryName;
            for (int i = 4; i < bline.length(); i++)
                countryName.push_back(bline[i]);
            countryCode = countryName;
        }
        break;
    }

    std::string regionName;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aline.length(); i++)
    {
        if (aline[i] == ',')
            count++;
        if (count == 2) {
            regionName.push_back(aline[i+1]);
            if (aline[i+2] == ',')
                break;
        }
    }
    countryRegionArray.push_back("Country: " + countryCode + " - Region: " + regionName);
}
```

Now this SORTA works, and I'm really not worries about efficiency at the moment since all i'm doing is making a script and this program will probably be scrapped once the script is made...

Here's the output...

```
Country: Andorra - Region: Aix\340s
Country: AD - Region: Aixirivali
Country: AD - Region: Aixirivall
Country: AD - Region: Aixirvall
```

As you can see, only the first line is being modified... I am stumped to be honest on why this is occuring... This isn't a homework assignment either, it's for my company's webpage to allow users who register a device to be able to pick from ANY country and region in the world...

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong please give me some insight :)... I'd greatly appreciate it!!!

Or if anyone can link me to a file that has both country NAMES and the region, that would be FANTASTIC... I was only able to find a country code - region file... :(

Comment: C++ is the wrong tool for this, use Python or awk or Perl or something that makes text processing trivial

Answer (score 2):

The first time through the loops you read the entire file:

```
while (getline(countryCodes, bline)) // if the file is readable
```

The next time through that reads nothing because you're already at the end of the file. That means `countryCode` isn't updated to `countryName` and stays set to the code.

You should read the files in once, store the data in memory, then search for country codes in the in-memory copy, instead of trying to loop over the entire file multiple times.  Think about sensible data structures to represent the lines in the files.

You should also look up how to use the `std::string::substr()` member function.